# Moses SMT translation difficulty with creating model (German to English) from two parallel file datasets

Tags: moses

*I try to create the model in Moses SMT from two parallel language files.
I completed all the stages of creation of the model.
But when I run translation:*

echo "Um zu bestimmen" | ~/mosesdecoder/bin/moses -f ~/mosesdecoder/0_my_test/align_2016.08.19_14.24.05/model/moses.ini

*it gives me some exception (in attached picture - in full detail, and written below (only exception body)), asking to execute the command:*

compile-lm --text yes /home/user/mosesdecoder/0_my_test/align_2016.08.19_14.24.05/lm/de_lm_proc.gz /home/user/mosesdecoder/0_my_test/align_2016.08.19_14.24.05/lm/de_lm_proc.gz.arpa

[attached picture of the result of running moses command mentioned above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8u7k.png)

.....
Exception: lm/read_arpa.cc:64 in void lm::ReadARPACounts(util::FilePiece&, std::vector&) threw FormatLoadException because `line == "iARPA"'.
This looks like an IRSTLM iARPA file.  You need an ARPA file.  Run
  compile-lm --text yes /home/user/mosesdecoder/0_my_test/align_2016.08.19_14.24.05/lm/de_lm_proc.gz /home/user/mosesdecoder/0_my_test/align_2016.08.19_14.24.05/lm/de_lm_proc.gz.arpa
first. Byte: 6

*But even after I executed that command I get the same exception.*

*What should I do?*